# Angular JSON Server to post data

Tags: angular

I am running one local application with help of json server so I do fake backend API and run my application, I do have users object as below in db.json file which is being read by user.service.ts

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "username": "jd",
      "firstName": "john",
      "lastName": "Dell",
      "password": "1234",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "age": 34,
      "companyId": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "firstName": "Den",
      "lastName": "Scott",
      "email": "den@gmail.com",
      "age": 43,
      "companyId": "1"
    }]
}
```

In my login page, I am sending username and password as entered by user, however as per given example [example from internet on login page for angular 2+](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example?file=app%2F_services%2Fauthentication.service.ts) , this uses post method to given service and it does insert data into users object rather then retrieving whole object given username and password.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`/users`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }
```

I would like to retrieve whole user object given username and password. above example insert/appends data into users object of db.json file with usernamem and password and id field, I would like to check if username and password matches return the whole object of that users.

Comment: did you create a fake backend like at the example?

Comment: and if you create a fake backend same as the example you will get http 404 error with this post call.

Comment: yes I have everything setup as  per example attached, only thing is that I dont want to insert new record, but want to retrive record based on given username and password

Comment: ok. did you changed the url for login? in the example login url is not /users

Comment: that is correct, it is http://localhost:3000/users

Comment: in the example url is: `/users/authenticate`

Comment: yes but I moved in my application to correct url

Comment: Ok. Take a look at mý github. I have a similar Project maybe it can help you. https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/AngularWithFakeApi

Comment: great help:  btw this fakeapi is on node ? do I need to install anything on node, I am really sorry I have very little experience on node, if you can help me with installing fakepi please

Comment: because I have db.json which helps to me to fake data, but I am not sure how to do in your case as it is on node I think, if you give instruction on how to setup backend.

Comment: You dont need to do any extra Thing if you have node in your Machine. Read readme file. I had added how to run app. And Change your DB.json in the İndex file under Fakeapi folder

Comment: Let me add a detailed answer

Comment: excellent @AbdurrahmanY, this application would havve been very good point for me to go ahead

Comment: glad to help you. take a look the answer if you cant run the project let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, using a proxy mechanism is better than doing this. In this way you don't have to make any changes in your services later.

Create a fakeapi with nodejs or with express quickly and run it on your local.

Add a proxy.conf.json to your angular project as following:

it means redirect all of urls that started with /api to localhost:3000

```
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target":"http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel":"debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Then start your angular application with command:
`ng serve --disable-host-check --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

if you want to get an example take a look at[my github account](https://github.com/abdurrahmanyildiz/AngularWithFakeApi) there is an project for this purpose.